# How do I Validate Email or Phone requirement in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In MVC I am using [Required(ErrorMessage="")] to validate my text.  How do I utilize a validation for an "Email or Phone Contact" textboxes in my model?  I now have the validation in my controller, which I would like to have in the model.

CONTROLLER...

```
        if (insuredInfo.InsuredHPhone == null && insuredInfo.InsuredWPhone == null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("InsuredHPhone", "Contact Number Required");
            isRequired = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a video tutorial on the official MVC website which might be worth watching:

http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-10082.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Scott Gutherie has a good blog post entitled '[ASP.NET MVC 2: Model Validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx)' in which he explains how you can add data annotations to your model. That should give you everything you need.